# Showing the positivity of $p$-adic density of zeroes of a polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and $p$ be a prime. Let $\nu_t(p)$ denote the number of solutions $\mathbf{x} \in ((\mathbb{Z}/p^t \mathbb{Z}))^*)^n$
to the congruence
$$
f( \mathbf{x} ) \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod }{p^t}).
$$
We define (something similar to the $p$-adic density)
$$
\mu(p) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{  p^t \nu_t(p) }{ \phi(p^t)^n }.
$$
Could someone please explain how to show
$$
\mu(p) > 0
$$
provided the equation $f( \mathbf{x} ) = 0$ has a non-singular solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$, the units of $p$-adic integers?
Thank you very much!

PS I asked this question in mathstack exchange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579876/showing-the-positivity-of-p-adic-density-of-zeroes-of-a-polynomial. I wasn't able to get an answer there so I thought I would try it on overflow.

PPS This came up when I was reading an article "Diophantine equations in the primes" http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00222-014-0508-1
I was interested in seeing the details but I couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: I guess the strategy is to use Hensel's lemma to show that, given a p-adic solution, if you move all but one of the variables a little bit (thus breaking the solution), then you can also move the last one to fix it. That's geometrically what a non-singular solution gives you. How little a little bit is depends on the equation, but there will be some concrete epsilon depending on eveything for which it will all be OK. Once you have this, you're then capable of generating p^{n-1} solutions mod p^{M+1} for every solution mod p^M (for all suff large M) and this will be enough.

Comment: It think this involves a standard argument using Hensel's lemma

Comment: It looks that the problem with applying lifting argument like Hensel lemma occurs when gradient at a p-adic root is p-adic 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments. Would it be possible that someone give me a detailed solution for a simple case say when $n=1$ or something, because I am not quite seeing how it works still... Thank you very much.

Comment: Telling your background (e.g., why was $n=1$ too hard?) and why you pose this question (e.g., working through a specific textbook or article on your own?) helps others to frame an appropriate response (e.g., do you really need lim, not liminf?). It is equivalent and more natural to consider positivity for the limiting behavior of $\nu_t(p)/p^{t(n-1)}$, and using $f(a+p\mathbf{y})$ for $a\in \mathbf{Z}_p^n$ varying through representatives of the $(p-1)^n$ elements of $(\mathbf{F}_p^{\times})^n$ shows that you can replace $\mathbf{Z}_p^{\times}$ with $\mathbf{Z}_p$ for the liminf version.

Comment: @eric The trouble I seem to be having is in order to apply hensel's lemma I need the derivative to be non-zero modulo $p$, but I don't quite see how to get this condition from the fact that the equation has a non-singular solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$. Could you possibly explain this bit by any chance? Thank you very much

Comment: You have a non-singular solution, so this means that the vector of partial derivatives of f evaluated at the point has a non-zero entry (by definition). That's the variable you need to move.

Comment: @eric I am still not quite seeing how to make it work... I would greatly appreciate if you could possibly provide me the details as a solution.

Comment: Did you know that Hensel's lemma can be formulated in a way that does not require nonsingular roots mod p?  Instead of requiring an $a \in \mathbf Z_p$ such that $f(a) \equiv 0 \bmod p$ and $f'(a) \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$, it's enough to have an $a$ such that $|f(a)|_p < |f'(a)|_p^2$. And this inequality is satisfied by all $a$ that are close to a nonsingular root in $\mathbf Z_p$.  See Theorem 7.1 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf. Your multivariable situation can be reduced to the one-variable situation by fixing all but one coordinate of a nonsingular solution.